# Adding html content after an element using css

Tags: html, css

like what the title says I'm trying to add a specific content to a part of a page. Obviously this is a desperate resort because I'm unable to modify the codes manually. So far this is what I have.

```
.paper-form input[name="elements[bd67ba9a-507b-4214-98a3-5abd36562937]"]:after {
content:'test';
 }
```

From what I did the name selector is working but once I added the `:after` It just doesn't work. Can anyone tell me I'm not used to using pseudo codes. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Though I don't have any specifics to give you, I have a feeling it's because you're applying to an `input`. Here's a related link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/css-after-pseudo-element-on-input-field

Comment: Oh I can't do that. God damn it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

:before and :after will not work with input elements, you have to write css like this

```
.paper-form:after {
    content:'test';
 }
```

well described in this article http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#before-after-content

Answer (score 0):

[Can I use the :after pseudo-element on an input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/css-after-pseudo-element-on-input-field)

*(originally quoted comment in post above)*

> ...the answer on which it is commenting has it right. What matters is
>   that input is a replaced element. The :before and :after
>   pseudo-elements form part of the content of the element which is
>   replaced, which is why it doesn't render. As is pointed out on that
>   page, on *`<hr>`*, which a void element but not replaced, :before and
>   :after pseudo-elements are rendered. – Alohci

Comment: Note that the quoted comment is incorrect, and the answer on which it is commenting has it right. What matters is that input is a **replaced element**. The :before and :after pseudo-elements form part of the content of the element which is replaced, which is why it doesn't render. As is pointed out on that page, on `<hr>`, which a void element but not replaced, :before and :after pseudo-elements are rendered.